# setGridSize(...) and text eliding

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistview

I am using QListView with QFileSystemModel to make a file manager. I am using `QListView::ListMode`. The problem I am facing is despite settings a grid size, the text does not get elided. Here is the code I am using.

```
import sys, os

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication( sys.argv )

fsm = QFileSystemModel()
lv = QListView()
lv.setViewMode( QListView.ListMode )

lv.setResizeMode( QListView.Adjust );
lv.setMovement( QListView.Static );
lv.setSelectionMode( QListView.ExtendedSelection );
lv.setWrapping( True );
lv.setFlow( QListView.LeftToRight );
lv.setTextElideMode( Qt.ElideRight );
lv.setUniformItemSizes( True );

lv.setIconSize( QSize( 48, 48 ) )
lv.setGridSize( QSize( 200, 56 ) )

lv.setModel( fsm )
lv.setRootIndex( fsm.setRootPath( "/path/to/my/folder/" ) )

lv.show()

app.exec_()
```

What I get is this garbage:

[image]

I do not have a clue why this is so? In the case I do not set a grid size, then the icons and text are rendered properly. Is this some Qt bug?

I'm using Debian Sid, Qt5 5.11.3+dfsg1-1, Python3/PyQt5: 3.7.3-1/5.11.3+dfsg-1+b3
I have even tried this with Qt5/C++ and the problem shows up even there.

Comment: In PyQt5  5.12.1 I see that it works correctly: https://i.imgur.com/q1Z7CFO.png, https://i.imgur.com/PrYuzcM.png. Maybe it's a Qt bug in the version you point out

Comment: @eyllanesc I see. And any idea why the text gets clipped much before 200 px? For example, I'm 100% sure that an icon size of 48 px, and the display name of "Desktop" will not take more than 200 px. As a matter of fact, for a fixed width font with point size 15, the "Desktop" has a typical width of 75 to 80 px. So why the clipping?

Comment: In the following image https://i.imgur.com/UwMgeK7.png I have placed a rule and it is observed that the width of the item is 100px, but the space between icons is 200px so I think the gridsize refers to it. On the other hand, what code is the one that you have implemented? Finally, for the item to occupy the width of 200px I have created a delegate that establishes that size: https://i.imgur.com/IQQ0nJy.png

Comment: "On the other hand, what code is the one that you have implemented?" Sorry which code are you talking about? File manager code? And could you please share the code of the delegate?

Comment: I speak of the code you provide in your question because as I point out I do not reproduce your error. The code of the delegate is simple: `class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def sizeHint(self, *args):
        s = super().sizeHint(*args)
        s.setWidth(200)
        return s`

Comment: Well the above code is just the MCVE to show the problem. The actual code is rather lengthy and is the [filemanager](https://gitlab.com/cubocore) for [CuboCore application suite](https://gitlab.com/cubocore/). It is implemented in Qt5/C++ but has the same issue as in python. I'll apply your code and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: This is lovely! It works like a charm. Thank you. Could you please put this as an answer below with those two images? I am sure quite a few people will face this issue and will be grateful for your answer.

Comment: okay, in a moment I will

Comment: I had used the tag c++ because the same issue appears in c++ as well.

Comment: I removed it because many C ++ users do not know python and vice versa, so I kept the python tag by the MCVE. I already published an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not get what the OP shows in the image, but I get the following:

[image]

It shows that the gridSize does not change the size of the item but the separation between them as shown by the ruler.

To change the width of the item I have implemented a delegate:

```py
# ...
class StyledItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        s = super().sizeHint(option, index)
        s.setWidth(200)
        return s

# ...
lv = QListView()
delegate = StyledItemDelegate(lv)
lv.setItemDelegate(delegate)
# ...
```

[image]